# How to setup ruby on rails debugger using vs code extension for WSL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed ruby on rails on WSL with windows VS code as Editor. To use Ruby Debugger with Vs code I have installed Ruby Extension. but it gives `Extension host terminated unexpectedly` error. How to set interpreter Path for Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

## 1) Ruby

VSCode will call Ruby provided it can already be found on your path as part of your standard environment.  To test this, at the command line run;

`ruby --version`

It should return something like;

`ruby 2.5.1p57`...

If you get an error instead, then you need to check how Ruby is set up on your system

## 2) Install debugging gems

- On the command line, run;

  `gem install bundler nokogiri ruby-debug-ide debase`

## 3) Set up VSCode Ruby debugging.

By default, VSCode assumes you have created the VSCode workspace in the root directory of your app, and the app's start point is main.rb .  Assuming this is true, configure debugging in VSCode as follows;

- Click the debug icon in Activity Bar on left
- Click green play icon beside “DEBUG” in top left
- Select “Ruby” from presented environment list
- To right of debug play button, click the down arrow beside “Debug Local File” and change to “Listen for rdebug-ide”
- Push gear button to right of the just selected "Listen for rdebug-ide"
- Edit "Listen for rdebug-ide" section of the presented launch.json file to include;

  ```
  "showDebuggerOutput" : true
  ```

## 4) Hopefully, you are now be good to go. :)